# Update a tif using gdal

Tags: python, gis, gdal

I have a geotif and want to update the value of one pixel/cell. What is the best way (resource safe) to save this change?
Do I have to use the WriteArray() function or is there a better solution for *updating* the same tif?

```
ds = gdal.Open("test.tif")
data = ds.ReadAsArray()

data[0][0] = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

If you open the dataset with the option `GA_Update`, instead of `GA_ReadOnly` you can update it directly. Also keep in mind that `ReadAsArray()` returns a numpy ndarray, which you have to adress with `data[0, 0]` instead of `data[0][0]`.

```
ds = gdal.Open("test.tif", GA_Update)
data = ds.ReadAsArray()

data[0, 0] = 1

ds.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(data)

# close the dataset to flush it to disk
ds = None
```

---

If your image has one band this code will work. If it has multiple bands, say 5, `ReadAsArray()` will return a 3-dimensional array and you have to loop through your bands to write them.

```
for band in range(5):
    ds.GetRasterBand(band+1).WriteArray(data[band, :, :])
```